# How do I get Tailwind grid to work on mobile under 640px?

Tags: tailwind-css

My issue is that I can not see my pricing page on mobile view. The top line class is what I am looking at. here is the code that I had

```
<div data-target="pricing.yearlyPlans" class="mt-12 space-y-4 sm:mt-16 sm:space-y-0 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-1 sm:gap-6 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-4">
  <%= render 'free_plan' %>
  <% Plan.yearly.sorted.each do |plan| %>
    <%= render layout: "subscriptions/styled_payment", locals: { plan: plan } do %>
      <%= link_to plan.name, new_subscription_path(plan: plan.id), class: "flex items-center justify-center mt-3 px-5 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white hover:text-white bg-tertiary-500 hover:bg-gray-900" %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Looking at the docs I figured I just need to do grid grid-cols-1 but when I do nothing at all shows up. the page is just blank where the pricing should be on any screen size

```
<div data-target="pricing.yearlyPlans" class="mt-12 space-y-4 grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-2  xl:grid-cols-4">
  <%= render 'free_plan' %>
  <% Plan.yearly.sorted.each do |plan| %>
    <%= render layout: "subscriptions/styled_payment", locals: { plan: plan } do %>
      <%= link_to plan.name, new_subscription_path(plan: plan.id), class: "flex items-center justify-center mt-3 px-5 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white hover:text-white bg-tertiary-500 hover:bg-gray-900" %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jamie Can you please post an image of your output, before and after. As it will be easier for people visiting this question in the future to have a better idea.

Comment: There wasn't much of an image as the page was blank. My issue ended up being a tailwind css purge, I think I white listed sm:grid-col-1

Comment: This was the classes I used for the out come
<div data-target="pricing.yearlyPlans" class="hidden flex-wrap items-center justify-center -mx-4">
        <div  class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-12 space-y-4 sm:mt-16 sm:space-y-0  sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-6 md:grid-cols-2 lg:max-w-4xl lg:mx-auto xl:max-w-none xl:mx-0 xl:grid-cols-4">

Comment: Also kindly refer this docs 
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-mobile-screens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this piece of code in your tailwind config file. By default tailwind media queries are set to min value that's why they do not work for screens under 640px. Make sure you do this using extend otherwise your other classes will get affected.

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    screens: { 'sm': { 'max': '640px' } },
  },
},
```

[Tailwind grid to work on mobile under 640px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAREK.png)

Comment: Hi @Fazeel My doubt is that, the tailwind docs say that they are by default approached with the mobile first approach, so they do recommend to use the default styles for the mobile, and break them up at the breakpoints (sm, md, lg, xl) to match the larger screens,  Kindly clarify me regarding this. Also a working example can be more useful for better understanding for the people visiting this question in the future. 

Comment: @SARANSURYA You should have a look on section "Targeting mobile screens"
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

I was working on responsive design, and I used sm breakpoint but it wasn't working for me when I visit my react app on mobile. By default media queries which tailwind generate contains min-value so sm breakpoint only works for screens 640px and wider.

Comment: So the default values should work for smaller screens right? As of what they mentioned in their YouTube channel. The classes without a breakpoint will by default work for mobile screens, and you can use the breakpoints from sm:,... 2xl: for the others right?  Anyways thanks for the info. Also kindly check this https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-mobile-screens

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is my solution, try it

```
max-sm:mb-6...
```